# C#: Moq : Message: System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: item => item.RouteId Non-overridable members

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have an interface `Arbiter`:

```
public interface Arbiter
{
    ContextData GetContextData();
}
```

I have a class that implements this interface:

```
public class ContextArbiter : Arbiter
{
   ContextData m_data;
    public ContextArbiter()
        :
        base()
    {
       m_data = new ContextData();
    }

     public ContextData GetContextData()
     {
          return m_data;
     }
}
```

I have another class that uses this interface:

```
public class SelectData 
{        
        private Arbiter m_Arbiter;
        public SelectData(Arbiter Arbiter)
        {            
            m_Arbiter = Arbiter;
        }

        public string RetrieveId()
        {
            return m_Arbiter.GetContextData().RouteId;            
        }
 }
```

Now I want to unit test this class:

```
public class SelectDataTest : UnitTestBase
{
    private Mock<Arbiter> Arbiter;
    private SelectData SelectData;

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void OneTimeSetup()
    {
        Arbiter= new Mock<Arbiter>();
        SelectData = new SelectData(Arbiter.Object);
    }     
}
```

Now this is my test:

```
[Test]
public void RetrieveRouteId_usingMockArbiter_shouldReturnCorrectRouteId()
{
    var ContextDataMock = new Mock<ContextData>();
    ContextDataMock.Setup(item => item.RouteId).Returns(Convert.ToString(64));
    ContextArbiter.Setup(p => p.GetContextData()).Returns(ContextDataMock.Object);

    Assert.AreEqual(Convert.ToString(64), SelectData.RetrieveRouteId());
}
```

When I run the test, I get the following error:

```
Message: System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: item => item.RouteId
Non-overridable members (here: ContextData.get_RouteId) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.
```

What am I doing wrong? Is this error because I am using a class directly in the Mock as in?

```
var ContextDataMock = new Mock<ContextData>();
```

Instead of an interface. What to do in this situation?

The definition of `ContextData` is shown here:

```
public class ContextData 
{
  public string AgencyId { get; set; }        
  public int VhId { get; set; }
  public string RouteId { get; set; }                
  public int EmployeeId { get; set; }     
}
```

Comment: You did not show us `ContextData`

Comment: @KlausGütter - Have added the definition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `RouteId`is not virtual, you cannot mock it. But since `ContextData` is a simple data class without behaviour, there is also no need to mock it. You can do simply:

```
ContextArbiter.Setup(p => p.GetContextData()).Returns(new ContextData { RouteId = "64" });
```